# How can I allow the user to type a TAB character in a Flex TextInput control?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, user-interface, flex3

I want to modify the Flex 3 TextInput control to accept a tab character as valid input (The app allows the user to enter an arbitrary delimiter string for file output formatting, and tab is a common use case).  However, clearly in the default implementation the tab key changes the form focus away from the selected control.

What I want, really, is a good way to allow arbitrary delimiter specifications in a UI, including (but not limited to) `TAB`, `,`, `|`, &c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not Flex, but this should get you on your way.

[How can I permit tab characters in a textfield in Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690816/how-can-i-permit-tab-characters-in-a-textfield-in-flash)